# ACE Editor line focus issue

Tags: ace-editor

I would like place some text in each line which is not div tag, and focus them by mouse click.
by default, ace editor only focus mouse cursor inside of the text of line.
I want focus on outside of line where I add element.
(https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1342)

I 'v inserted my code in lib/ace/layer/text.js like as following.(only pay attention for mingji's comment)

this.$renderLine = function(stringBuilder, row, onlyContents, foldLine) {

```
var lineNumber = row;
if (!foldLine && foldLine != false)
    foldLine = this.session.getFoldLine(row);

if (foldLine)
    var tokens = this.$getFoldLineTokens(row, foldLine);
else
    var tokens = this.session.getTokens(row);


if (!onlyContents) {
    stringBuilder.push(
        "<div class='ace_line' style='height:", this.config.lineHeight, "px'>"
    );
}

if (tokens.length) {
    var splits = this.session.getRowSplitData(row);
    if (splits && splits.length)
        this.$renderWrappedLine(stringBuilder, tokens, splits, onlyContents);
    else
        this.$renderSimpleLine(stringBuilder, tokens);
}

if (this.showInvisibles) {
    if (foldLine)
        row = foldLine.end.row

    stringBuilder.push(
        "<span class='ace_invisible'>",
        row == this.session.getLength() - 1 ? this.EOF_CHAR : this.EOL_CHAR,
        "</span>"
    );
}

****//<<2013.03.30 mingji add this code for comment input
stringBuilder.push(
    "<table id='notegrid",lineNumber,"' border='0' class='ace_notecomment' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='height:", this.config.lineHeight-4, "px;'> \
    <tr id='R",lineNumber,"'> \
    <td class='ace_notecomment_cn' >//note_cn</td> \
    <td class='ace_notecomment_en' >//note_en</td> \
    </tr> \
    </table>"
);
//>>**

if (!onlyContents)
    stringBuilder.push("</div>");
```

};

like this some table text displayed in my editor's each line.
but I cant focus mouse cursor on line's table td element.

Comment: From the question it's not clear what do you mean, if you need to focus editor when clicking on something else call `editor.focus()` from mousedown listener.

A little bit longer explanation of why you need this, and how exactly it's supposed to behave would be helpful.

Comment: I 'v attached my mockup image in this url.(https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1342)